# Spring and domain objects

Tags: spring

> Domain objects should not be created through ApplicationContext

This is a tip mentioned in spring best practices.

What is the rationale behind avoiding Spring let control the domain objects. Is this a design pattern recommendation?

Answer (score 1):

For the most part your domain objects represent data that changes. If this would be created through `ApplicationContext` it would mean that you are persisting your operational data into XML or Java classes (via `JavaConfig`) instead of for example database which is way more suited to such purposes.

I'm wondering if you are getting concepts mixed here. Typically you DO let Spring control your domain objects via creating `@Repository` or `@Service` classes that instantiate and persist the domain objects for you. You just use `JdcbTemplate`s or some ORM libraries inside these classes to handle the creating and persisting instead of `ApplicationContext` which would make no sense in most cases as explained in the first part of my answer.

Comment: Do you know the anemic domain model anti-pattern? http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html `Model`s at least in applications beyond CRUD should contain data and behavior. To be able to reuse and inject behavior injecting via Spring can be the right _tool_ as @DaveNewton pointed out.

Comment: I do know it, but I'm still not sure I agree with you. Behaviour in domain objects would typically refer to something the model objects can do internally and this should rarely require injection. But I guess this has no one right answer. Doesn't DDD have repositories and aggregates for the things you describe and those could well be managed by Spring ApplicationContext?

Answer (score 1):

There's no great *reason* to create domain objects through Spring... except...

Bear in mind that document is dated. Some techniques weren't as widespread then, like AOP.

The point is that unless you *need* something Spring offers, like its DI or AOP support, there's no reason to use it to create every application object. Note also that through byte-code weaving you can do both DI and AOP without having to instantiate objects through Spring.

It boils down to using the "right" tool for the job, but "right" varies *wildly* across apps.

Comment: In addition, in some scenarios you are not in control how domain objects are created even in this cases Spring allows us to inject things to avoid an otherwise anemic domain model.
http://olivergierke.de/2009/05/using-springs-configurable-in-three-easy-steps/

Comment: @Andreas I didn't want to get into the possible byte-code magics, but I'll update my answer anyway. In the real world I haven't run across too many places doing this, mostly out of fear.

Comment: It's always about balancing byte-code magic versus service-locator anti pattern :-). At least for Hibernate you can inject when objects materialize from the db.

Answer (score 0):

Spring is great as a DI framework however to use it to create domain objects is just overkill also if you start using it that way you will have too many bean xml configuration or objects to be handled by framework.

It may be an overuse which is suggested to be avoided.